# Jquery “go to” doesn’t work correctly inside php “while loop”

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Can anyone help me. I’m trying to make jquery go to function while click on a div. Function works but it goes always on the same ID, first one.
Here is the code:

```
<?php do { ?>
<div class=“editNews”></div>
<script>
$(function() {
$(“.editNews”).on(“click touchstart”, function(e) {
```

Here I would like to execute jquery and than go to

```
window.location = “inserNews.php?id=<?php echo $row_rsNews[“NewsID”]; ?>;
});
e.stopPropagation()
});
});
</script>
<?php } while ($row_rsNews = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsNews))?>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Among other things, `lcation` is misspelled - make sure to post *actual* code representing the explained issue. The loop itself is "wrong" because it binds to the same set of `$(".editNews")` element(s) each time, regardless of the "NewsID" of the row. *Look at the resulting HTML* to see this flaw, which would result in "goes to the same ID".

Comment: those are not standard quote marks, i dont know if JavaScript cares, but but the php does

Comment: @user2864740 I know what you mean, thanks, now it works